# How to mutex on a static function (in Java)?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, mutex

I've been struggling with java mutexing for a while now, I'm trying to have `ByteIterator` objects each print a new (and unique) `byte[]` they get from the `JobQueue`, but they continually print repeat values

How can i make sure only one thread enters the static method `JobQueue.getByte()` at a time?

Heres what i've tried:

- Syncronised methods *and* syncronised statments (with various lock objs)

  - on both the thread `ByteIterator` and the `JobQueue` static method
- Reentrant locks on both
- Single permit semaphore (on both)

and the code in question (`getByte()`):

```java
public class JobQueue{
    private static volatile Byte[] nextByte; 
    private static final Byte realMin = 0; // fixed values for debuging
    private static final Byte realMax = (byte) 89; 

    public static void initJobQueue(){
        nextByte = new Byte[ByteIterator.fleet.length];
        for (int i=0; i<nextByte.length; i++) nextByte[i]=realMin;
    }

    //FIXME: this is the error prone method! 
    // This section should only be accessed by one thread at a time
    //  (ie none recive a duplicate byte)
    public static Byte[] getByte(){
        if(nextByte==null || checkEndVal(nextByte)) return null;

        Byte[] currentByte = nextByte;
    
        // iterate the value
        for (int i = 0; i < nextByte.length; i++) {
            if (nextByte[i]==realMax){
                nextByte[i]=realMin;
            } else{
                nextByte[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(checkEndVal(nextByte)) nextByte=null;
        return currentByte;
    }
```

The running code and thread obj

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ByteIterator implements Runnable{  
     // ---- Game state settings (public and fixed for debugging) 
    public static final int[] fleet = {2,3};
    public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 5;

    public static final String lockingObject="test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int threadCount = 2;
        JobQueue.initJobQueue(); // setup the jobQueue

        // ---- Create the threads
        Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[threadCount]; 
        for(int i=0; i<threadCount; i++){
            threadArray[i] = new Thread(new ByteIterator());
            threadArray[i].start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){ // prints each next byte array
        Byte[] foo = JobQueue.getByte();

        while(foo != null){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo));
            synchronized (lockingObject) {
                foo = JobQueue.getByte();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SolomonSlow I tried a lot of things (listed above) would it be more useful to give code snippets of each attempt? Ie I have put variations of `synchronized(lock)` in many places but none changed outcome

Comment: Deleted my previous comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making all sorts of mistakes. No single fix makes it work because you have multiple errors; you need to fix *all of them*.

### Locking on public things

Don't do that. Locks are incredibly hard to reason about as is, if you make the lock object 'public', as in, tons of code all over the system might hold a ref to that object, you're making it from 'difficult' to 'utterly impossible'. Locking on a string is therefore **a capital mistake**, do not, ever, do that.

Make your own lock objects. And make sure they are private. And make sure that everything that needs to lock on it, locks on *the same object*. In some iterations of this question (you've been editing it), you had a non-static field, meaning each `lockingObject` field in every instance of `ByteIterator` was pointing at a different object. `synchronized(x)` does **nothing** except interact with other `synchronized(z)` statements, where `z` and `x` are pointing at the same object (`z == x` would be true).

### Locks aren't applied consistently

Your first call in ByteIterator's run is `getByte()`, which isn't in any synchronized block. Only the while loop that follows does this.

### Locks are applied in the wrong place

Clearly the locking behaviour should occur in `getByte()`. Not in your ByteIterator run() method.

### Primitive v reference types

`Byte` is the wrapper type. You don't want that unless you really, really know what you are doing. You write `byte[]`. No, `Byte` and `byte` are not synonyms. `Byte` bad, `byte` good (later on in your java career you might learn when `Byte` is actually desired. It isn't, here).

### Reference confusion

Count the amount of `new` that will be executed in your code. That many objects exist. **And not a single one more**.

So let's go counting. You make a bunch of new ByteIterator objects, (1 per `threadCount`), as well as threads, but that's not what we are interested in. We're interested in `Byte[]` objects.

Your JobQueue class has a static `initJobQueue` method. This method is invoked **only once**. This method executes some form of `new Byte[]` **only once**.

End of count.

That means **there is only 1 Byte array FOR YOUR ENTIRE APPLICATION**.

All threads are sharing that byte array. Every write you make? It's all going to the same memory position. Every thread is jus writing all over each others business and the end result is a coinflippy mess (in the sense that every run will get you likely different results, the way threads interact is usually highly irregular, i.e. not repeatable).

### Lets fix all 5 errors then

Get every attempt to lock in any form out of your main class and `ByteIterator`.

Then:

```
public class JobQueue {
    private static volatile byte[] nextByte; 
    private static final byte realMin = 0; // fixed values for debuging
    private static final byte realMax = (byte) 89; 
    private static final Object lock = new Object(); // private!

    public static void initJobQueue() {
        nextByte = new Byte[ByteIterator.fleet.length];
        for (int i=0; i<nextByte.length; i++) nextByte[i]=realMin;
    }

    public static Byte[] getByte() {
      synchronized (lock) {
        if(nextByte==null || checkEndVal(nextByte)) return null;

//         Byte[] currentByte = nextByte; -- THIS DOES NOT MAKE A COPY --
        byte[] currentByte = Arrays.copyOf(nextByte);
    
        // iterate the value
        for (int i = 0; i < nextByte.length; i++) {
            if (currentByte[i]==realMax) {
                currentByte[i]=realMin;
            } else { 
                currentByte[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(checkEndVal(currentByte)) nextByte=null;
        nextByte = currentByte;
        return currentByte;
    }
```

The crucial clue is `Arrays.copyOf`. As per the javadoc, that **makes a new array**. The first call to `getByte()` will dutifully run synchronized (one-at-a-time) and returns a byte array back to its caller. Your code will then, while the first thread is still working on its byte array, call `getByte()` again which would write all over that one single byte array, causing a mess. This code does not do that - instead it makes a clone (`Arrays.copyOf` runs `new byte[]` somewhere inside it, so, that's +1), and then modifies that clone, and then returns that clone.

Every byte array that is returned by `getByte()` is **never modified** by anything except, possibly, the code you gave it to.

Comment: For the `Byte[]` vs `byte[]` discussion, i call `Arrays.stream(nextByte)` inside some of the code i removed from `getByte()` which according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has to be `Byte[]`
I also use the `ByteIterator` obj to normally put the returned value into a list, which doesn't support primitive types, would you still use `byte[]`?

Comment: Yes, use `byte[]` - convert byte to Byte when storing in a list (if those lists are somewhat large, you don't wanna do that, a `List<Byte>` is about 32 times less efficient than a `byte[]`, it adds up fast), and don't stream byte arrays like that.

Answer (score 0):

As posted, the `lockingObject` is an instance variable of `ByteIterator`, so of course every thread has its own copy and no two threads share the same lock.

Use `synchronized static` which has a lock object per-class instead of per-instance:

```java
public synchronized static Byte[] getByte() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: switching it to `static` in `ByteIterator` or even Solomon's suggestion of `private static final Object lock=new Object()` doesn't change the outcome, neither does just updating `getByte()` to be `synchronized`

Comment: In addition to what @rzwitserloot said, you're also printing outside of the synchronization, and forgetting that threads may be scheduled arbitrarily. I added a thread ID to your printout statement and that explains all "out of order" outputs.

Comment: I had a thread ID previously, but I count the duplicates with a shell script, and it was easier to remove ID than to regex out the ID. In usual practice, I don't print the values, and am aware that order isn't consistent